# PHP code either is commented out or Produces Internal Server Error 500

Tags: php, embed

```
<div class="thumb_container centered">
    <?php
        foreach (glob("../images/*.{jpg,png}") as $filename) {
         echo '<img src="' . $filename . '">';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

This snippet will not work embedded inside of a HTML document. If I save the file with .php extension, it errors out and `gives internal server error 500`. If I save it as a .html, the script is commented out and it prints `';}?>` inside the div.  I have also set the `permissions to 755`, but still no go.

How do I have this script run?

Comment: Have you checked the error log files to see the reason for the 500 status code?

Comment: The code that you have shared has no errors which would cause Internal Server Error 500. By any chance are you using any php 4.3 - version?

Comment: What are the perms and owners of the parent folders?  Apache needs access all the way up the chain.

Comment: Havelock - No, I'm not sure which log it would be, I'm using host gator for now with cPanel, would you know what the log file would be called, or is it different for all domain hosts?

Hanky Panky - The version is 5.4.29 I believe, but at least 5.4.

Rachael - I'll check that and post back.

Comment: Permissions on folders are 755, but the images are 644. Any ideas on how to change the file permissions for a large number of files at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is maybe a problem with permissions on `../images/` and/or it's files. Try to set the permissions readable for your webserver user.

The file extension `.php` is of course the right one so that the files is parsed by PHP.

You can check also your error log, mostly located in `/var/log/`.

Comment: Permissions on folders are 755, but the images are 644. Any ideas on how to change the file permissions for a large number of files at once?

Comment: An Unix machines you can set them with `chmod -R 0664` recursive for your folder.

Comment: Ok so the page loads now, but the script itself doesn't load the repeated <img> tags on the page. But I am 1 step closer thanks.

Comment: With `var_dump(glob("../images/*.{jpg,png}"));` you can watch the whole array and check different conditions to match your wishes.